# Cannot import livestreamer module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I am new to python and just tried to import the live streamer module (http://livestreamer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) in Python.

The module is installed at:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/livestreamer-1.8.0-py2.7.egg
```

My script is pretty much one line:

```
from livestreamer import Livestreamer
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Livestreamer
```

I searched the web for similar issues, but couldn't find any related to this module, but apparently it's a circular dependent import...? I don't know how to fix this.

Note: My script works when it's just:

```
import livestreamer
```

I'd say the modules doesn't contain a class called Livestreamer, but the documentation says so.

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly installed Livestreamer.? R u experienced any error ..?

Try running this command from the package

> pip install setup.py